# Куда то девается setTimeout (setInterval)

Tags: jquery, javascript

Нужен терапевтический `«дебаунцер»`,чтобы ховер НЕ работал слишком резко:

```
$('p').text('Заработала страничка, сделай hover меня');

$('p').hover(
function () {
    k=setInterval(show_tip('div'),2000); // <- почему нет задержки 2 сек??
},
function () {
    hide_tip('div');
});

function show_tip(target) {$(target).fadeIn(300);}
function hide_tip(target) {clearInterval(k); $(target).fadeOut(300);}
```

- Но `setInterval` не хочет меня спасать, может спасёте Вы (только не на бижу фрилансеров)?
- Ах да, фиддл же: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/B93bL/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@Олег Б](/users/11481/%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3-%D0%B1)](/users/11481/%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3-%D0%B1) , потому-что аргументом для `setTimeout` и `setInterval` является функция а не `undefined` как у вас :)

*hint: `show_tip('div')` выполнится сразу, т.к. скрипт попытается вычислить аргумент для функции setInterval)* (я вчера [отвечал](/questions/249448#249452) на точно такой-же вопрос)

вы же в hover не пишете почему-то так ?

```
$('p').hover(
    k=setInterval(show_tip('div'),2000); // <- почему нет задержки 2 сек??
,
    hide_tip('div');
);
```

вот и в `setInterval` тоже надо давать аргументом функцию, а не её результат.

Comment: ссылка битая должна быть `http://hashcode.ru/questions/<qid>#<aid>`

Comment: да никак не могу привыкнуть что там js вместо просто ссылки...

Comment: @eicto, всё бы ничего, но только у меня там `this`, а конструкция

    k=setInterval( function(){ show_tip(this); },3000);

уже как я понимаю передает другой this, мб есть какие то варианты? вот приблизительно как тут: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/nGaHh/

хотя я нашёл вариант:

    $('p').hover(
         function(){ 
            mytarget = this;
            setTimeout(function(){ show_tip(mytarget); }, 600); },
         function(){ hide_tip(this); }    
    );

Comment: @Олег Б `var` не забывайте. тут у вас `mytarget` вылез в глобальный контекст без `var`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/B93bL/6